# how i can sum qty by grouping name of goods?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How i can sum qty by grouping name of goods?

```
<table border="1">
  <tr><th>ID</th><th>Name of Goods</th><th>Qty</th></tr>
  <tr><td>110</td><td>BOOK</td><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>111</td><td>Pencil</td><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>110</td><td>BOOK</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>112</td><td>Ruler</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>112</td><td>Ruler</td><td>1</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `each` tr and `filter` to implement your requirement:

```
   $("button").click(function(){
   var group = [];
   $("tr").each(function(index,item){
       if(index > 0){
           let id = $(item).find('td').eq(0).text();
           let name = $(item).find('td').eq(1).text();
           let count = parseInt($(item).find('td').eq(2).text());
           let exist = group.filter(c=>c.name == name)[0];
           if(exist != undefined){
            exist.count += count;
           }else{
             group.push({id : id, name: name, count : count});
           }
       }
   });
   console.log(group);
});
```

Display result in table:

```
 $.each(group, function(index,item){
     $('#result tr:last').after('<tr>' + '<td>'+ item.id + '</td>' + '<td>'+ item.name + '</td>'+ '<td>'+ item.count + '</td>' + '</tr>');
 });
```

```js
$("button").click(function(){
   var group = [];
   $("#product tr").each(function(index,item){
       if(index > 0){
           let id = $(item).find('td').eq(0).text();
           let name = $(item).find('td').eq(1).text();
           let count = parseInt($(item).find('td').eq(2).text());
           let exist = group.filter(c=>c.name == name)[0];
           if(exist != undefined){
            exist.count += count;
           }else{
             group.push({id : id, name: name, count : count});
           }
       }
   });
   $.each(group, function(index,item){
   $('#result tr:last').after('<tr>' + '<td>'+ item.id + '</td>' + '<td>'+ item.name + '</td>'+ '<td>'+ item.count + '</td>' + '</tr>');
   });
   //console.log(group);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="product" border="1">
  <tr><th>ID</th><th>Name of Goods</th><th>Qty</th></tr>
  <tr><td>110</td><td>BOOK</td><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>111</td><td>Pencil</td><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>110</td><td>BOOK</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>112</td><td>Ruler</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>112</td><td>Ruler</td><td>1</td></tr>
</table>

<button  click="sum()">Sum</button>

<table id="result" border="1">
<tbody>
  <tr><th>ID</th><th>Name of Goods</th><th>Qty</th></tr>
</tbody> 
</table>
```

Comment: I do not need you vote up, please do not vote down please, only provide a help for OP

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, that's work. I'm not vote down your answer, i dont know what happened.

Answer (score -1):

You can make a JavaScript object with one property for each unique "Name of Goods" in your table.

Looping through the rows, if the property name already exists, you add the 'Qty' for that row to the existing count, and if the property doesn't yet exist, you create the property and assign the 'Qty' for that row as its value.

(To use the values stored in the `counts` JavaScript object, you can get an array of the object's property names with `Object.keys(counts)` and loop through it to get the value stored in each of the object's named properties.)

This example shows how it all works.

```js
// Get a list of all the `tr` elements on the page and call it `rows`
const rows = document.getElementsByTagName("TR");
// Make an empty JS object and call it `counts`
const counts = {};

// Loop through the list of `tr` elements (calling the current tr `row`)
for(let row of rows){
  // Get a list of `td` elements in the current `tr` element, and call it `cells`
  const cells = row.getElementsByTagName("TD");
  // If the current `tr` element has any `td` elements in it... 
  if(cells.length){
    const name = cells[1].innerHTML; // Contents of second `td` element
    const qty = cells[2].innerHTML; // Contents of third `td` element
    // If we've seen this name before...
    if(counts[name]){
      // Add `qty` to the existing property's value
      counts[name] += parseInt(qty);
    }
    // Otherwise...
    else {
       // Make a new property using `name` as its name and `qty` as its value
      counts[name] = parseInt(qty);
    }
  }
}

// Print contents of the `counts` object
const categories = Object.keys(counts); // Get property names
for(let category of categories){
  const count = counts[category]; // Get property values
  console.log(category + ": " + count); // Print property names and values
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr><th>ID</th><th>Name of Goods</th><th>Qty</th></tr>
  <tr><td>110</td><td>BOOK</td><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>111</td><td>Pencil</td><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>110</td><td>BOOK</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>112</td><td>Ruler</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>112</td><td>Ruler</td><td>1</td></tr>
</table>
```